# Prevent displaying data for another object in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my `React/Redux` app, I have a `timelineReducer` that allows me to centrally manage the timeline of different objects such as projects, tasks, etc.

Recently discovered a bug that I had not noticed before because it requires a set of circumstances for it to occur.

When I request the timeline of a parent object, I call an action which makes an API call and sets the `timeline: []` array in the `timelineReducer`.

If, however, I request `Project A` and quickly change my mind and go into `Task B` and happen to have a slow network connection at the time, I end up with timeline data that belongs to `Project A` even though I'm in `Task B`'s page.

I do have clean up routines that I perform on `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle method but looks like the clean up routine gets completed before the network response arrives and sets the `timeline: []` array in my reducer and I end up with the wrong  data.

Has anyone faced such a situation? Before I try to reinvent the wheel, I wanted to see if there's a standard approach in these situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced a similar situation where i added a reference object along with the timeline[], like `{project:'A',timeline:[]}` was my payload to reducer. So it means this timeline is in reference to project A and which ever component which uses this array will first verify the value of project to confirm its the array of project A

Comment: That's exactly what I thought about doing as well. I appreciate your sharing your approach.

Comment: @Sam  Cool. ＼（^０＾）／